# Knitting Rmarkdown to word.doc: How to avoid table of content's heading in TOC

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, rstudio

This is a sample of my Rmarkdown file. I have provided a report template and a toc is generated. However the toc heading is also numbered so my chapters begin at 2. How can i turn off toc heading numbering and make sure that the toc isnt chapter 1? I am using Rstudio.

```
---
title: mytitle"
author: "me"
date: "2/1/2021"
bibliography: mybibfile.bib
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    reference_docx: "template.docx"
---
\newpage
# Flomvarslig Status Quo
## Eksisterende systemer
### A
### B
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code, it works fine from my side. I think the problem may be with the `template.docx` you're using.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Thank you :)